# AsyncQueryHandler onQueryComplete Listener is null

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using `AsyncQueryHandler` in `getview();`
Each item in `getview()` makes an asynchoronous query.

But sometimes, `onqueryComplete()` returns `null`.

```
public class CustomAsyncHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {

    private WeakReference<AsyncQueryListener> mListener;

    public interface AsyncQueryListener {
        void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor);
    }

    public CustomAsyncHandler(ContentResolver cr, AsyncQueryListener listener) {
        super(cr);
        mListener = new WeakReference<AsyncQueryListener>(listener);
    }

    public CustomAsyncHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
        super(cr);
    }

    /**
     * Assign the given {@link AsyncQueryListener} to receive query events from
     * asynchronous calls. Will replace any existing listener.
     */
    public void setQueryListener(AsyncQueryListener listener) {
        mListener = new WeakReference<AsyncQueryListener>(listener);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
        final AsyncQueryListener listener = mListener.get();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onQueryComplete(token, cookie, cursor);
        } else if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

}
```

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: `AsyncQueryHandler#onQueryComplete` is a "void" method so it cannot return anything

Comment: yah its true.. !  but   in final AsyncQueryListener listener = mListener.get();              listener is null.

Comment: I got a problem its because of weakreference .

Comment: no one has any idea what is mListener and what mListener.get() does...

Comment: I got the problem it is because of weakereference . I am trying to use all queries with one object listener. so when task is completed it removes listerner

Comment: and what is that WeakReference for?

Comment: AsyncQueryHandler has weakreference to its listener  so when task completed it should be Garbage collected.

Comment: @NiravKhunt did you solve the problem? I am facing it